# Updating from firebase 6.0 to 6.1 is breaking my cloud functions app initialization

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

After being forced to update my firebase code to 6.1, I have come across the issue of this code snippet not properly checking to see if the default app has been initialized.

```
if(!admin.apps.length)
{   
   admin.initializeApp();
}
```

This was working fine before and now it never initializes the app.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code to

```
if(!admin.apps.length || admin.apps.length === 1)
{   
   admin.initializeApp();
}
```

it turns out that admin.apps length is 1 when there isn't a default app initialized and it now works correctly as it did before. Hopefully this helps out someone else with the same problem.